# CSS change attributes for a single character

Tags: html, css, fonts, character, tampermonkey

I'm making a tampermokey script that will change a webpage's letter colors. What it has to do is change each letter's color with a specific color (for example, each 'a' is red, 'b' green...).

There is nothing about this in Google. I can't use span since I'm editing a HTML document (spanning with different classes each letter is not the solution).

How can I change the font color for a specific character?

Comment: Why can't you use <span>?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way will be to search for the single character and replace it with a container containig that character.
eg: `hello world` should become

```
<span class='ch_h'>h</span>
<span class='ch_e'>e</span>
<span class='ch_l'>l</span>
<span class='ch_l'>l</span>
<span class='ch_o'>o</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<span class='ch_w'>w</span>
```

and so on...